# How to make locally created file in jupyterlab visible in AWS S3 running in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, jupyter-lab

I am trying to save data from **jupyter** lab to AWS S3 in Kubenretes.

Once jupyter lab comes up I can see data from S3 bucket "testml1" perfect.

However if I open a **terminal** in jupyter notebook and create some
**file** this is NOT visible:

1. visible in left sidebar at jupyter
2. nor in S3

```
    extraConfig: |-
      c.ServerProxy.host_whitelist = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1", "rapidsai-scheduler"]
      from s3contents import S3ContentsManager
      
      from hybridcontents import HybridContentsManager
      from notebook.services.contents.largefilemanager import LargeFileManager
      c = get_config()
    
      c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = HybridContentsManager
      
      c.HybridContentsManager.manager_classes = {
          # Associate the root directory with an S3ContentsManager.
          # This manager will receive all requests that don"t fall under any of the
          # other managers.
          "": S3ContentsManager,
          # Associate /directory with a LargeFileManager.
      }
      
      c.HybridContentsManager.manager_kwargs = {
          # Args for root S3ContentsManager.
          "": {
              "access_key_id": "...",
              "secret_access_key": "...",
              "bucket": "testml1",
              # "root_dir": "/home/jovyan",
          },
      }
```

it almost feels like terminal and the storage it is using, is totally separated from the one which is used by **HybridContentsManager**. and **S3ContentsManager**

Answer (score 1):

Try associating the mapped S3 bucket to the Notebook working directory by uncommenting the `# "root_dir": "/home/jovyan",` line. That should make all your contents being mapped to S3, where new notebooks or files created in that context to be added to your bucket.

If you need multiple directories (e.g. S3 buckets, etc) you could use additional storage volumes that are supported by JupyterHub and documented in the [Z2JH readthedocs](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-storage.html).

Comment: Thansk it wokred

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration which worked but still.

Would it be possible to have **local_directory** and **AWS S3 content** all together ??

```
      c.ServerProxy.host_whitelist = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1", "rapidsai-scheduler"]
      # ----------------
      from s3contents import S3ContentsManager
      from hybridcontents import HybridContentsManager
      from notebook.services.contents.largefilemanager import LargeFileManager
      #from IPython.html.services.contents.filemanager import FileContentsManager
      c = get_config()
      
      c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = HybridContentsManager
      
      c.HybridContentsManager.manager_classes = {
          # Associate the root directory with an S3ContentsManager.
          # This manager will receive all requests that don"t fall under any of the
          # other managers.
          "": S3ContentsManager,
          # Associate /directory with a LargeFileManager.
          "local_directory": LargeFileManager,
      }
      
      c.HybridContentsManager.manager_kwargs = {
          # Args for root S3ContentsManager.
          "": {
              "access_key_id": "...",
              "secret_access_key": "...",
              "bucket": "testml1",
          },
          "local_directory": {
              "root_dir": "/home/jovyan",
          },
      }
```

Comment: any idea on how it would work for the notebook to correctly report the path it is in? i.e. `os.getcwd()` always points to `root_dir` then